# Función lambda que elimine los dígitos de una cadena [Python]

Tags: python, lambda

resulta que no paro de darle vueltas y pues no me termina de salir. Lo que tengo de momento es esto, creo que me falla el `else` del final que no entra siempre pero, claro, la sintaxis me está dando problemas y me arroja un error cuando intento hacerlo de otra forma.

```
quitar_digitos = (
    lambda s: ""
    if s == ""
    else s[0]
    if not s[0] in "0123456789"
    else quitar_digitos(s[1:])
)
```

Solo me devuelve la primera letra y necesito toda la cadena.

Comment: Hola. ¿Estás tratando de usar recursión desde una función lambda?

Comment: Si resulta que e empezado a cambiar algunas cosillas y ya e conseguirlo arreglarlo, me a quedado asi:                                      quitar_digitos = lambda s: '' if s == '' else  s[0] + quitar_digitos(s[1:]) if (s[0] not in '0123456789')  else quitar_digitos(s[1:])

Comment: Te lo preguntaba porque creo que te estás complicando, ¿no es más fácil hacer algo como esto? `quitar_digitos = ''.join(filter(lambda letra: letra not in '0123456789', 'aaa123bb990cc01'))`, o tal vez: `''.join(filter(lambda letra: not letra.isdigit(), 'aaa123bb990cc01'))`

Comment: La solución de César sería la más elegante en mi opinión y debería ser una respuesta aceptada en lugar de comentario.